# move_uploaded_files php changing image but keeps the old name

Tags: php

I am trying to update user image in php and this is how my code looks.

```
$u_image = $_FILES['u_image']['name'];
            $image_tmp = $_FILES['u_image']['tmp_name'];



move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "user/user_images/$user_image");
```

The function is replacing the old default image with new one but it is not renaming the old photo file. As a result i have a new photo with old name extension and so no image display on html page.

before update 
[old file] ['oldname.jpg']
after update
[new file] ['oldname.jpg']

Comment: What is the result of move_uploaded_file? If it is false, check you log-files. If it is true, then you upload your file to an unexpected destination. Use absolute Paths in this case. But there are so many other possible reasons. e.g. Open-BaseDir-Restrictions, permissions, etc. I bet you find the error in your log-file.

Comment: photo is moved to the folder. but the old name is not changed to new name. i have updated my question

Comment: false variable-name? move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "user/user_images/$user_image"); should be move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "user/user_images/$u_image");

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong variable name:

```
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "user/user_images/$user_image");
```

should be changed to:

```
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "user/user_images/$u_image");
```